# How to manipulate SOAP response tags with Viewflex ZOAP library in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, soap, laminas

I was trying to get `<groupId>` tag inside of `<workerGroup>` tag like so

```
<ns2:workerGroup>
    <ns2:groupId>288</ns2:groupId>
    <ns2:groupId>6</ns2:groupId>
    <ns2:groupId>125</ns2:groupId>
    <ns2:groupId>106</ns2:groupId>
    <ns2:groupId>155</ns2:groupId>
</ns2:workerGroup>
```

but instead I'm getting this

```
<workerGroup>
    <xsd:int>1</xsd:int>
    <xsd:int>1</xsd:int>
</workerGroup>
```

In my opinion the reason behind this logic error is `array`

While creating Worker object I'm giving an `array` as an argument

```
public static function getWorker()
    {
        $operatorB2b = Role::where('group', 'operator')->first()->users;
        $operatorB2c = Role::where('group', 'operator')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first()->users;
        $merged = $operatorB2b->merge($operatorB2c);
        $workers = [];

        foreach ($merged as $worker) {
            $workers[] = new Worker($worker->id, $worker->first_name, $worker->surname ? $worker->surname : '', '', 1, [1, 1], 1);
        }

        $main = new Main(
            new Personnel(
                new Service(
                    'System', 'System', 1, [1,1]
                ), $workers
            )
        );
        
        return $main;
    }
```

Worker Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Soap\Types;

class Worker
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    public $workerId = 1;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $name;
    
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $surname;
    

    /**
     * @var string 
     */
    public $secondName;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    public $workerStatus = 1;
    
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $workerGroup;
    
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $workerNumber;
    /**
     * Product constructor.
     */
    public function __construct($id, $name = '', $surname = '', $secondName = '', $workerStatus, $workerGroup, $workerNumber = '')
    {
        $this->workerId = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->surname = $surname;
        $this->secondName = $secondName;
        $this->workerStatus = $workerStatus;
        $this->workerGroup = $workerGroup;
        $this->workerNumber = $workerNumber;
    }
}
```

**Does anyone knows how to solve this issue**

Package link:
https://github.com/viewflex/zoap